# Importar el component table con parametros en otro componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

quiero que mi componente table sea global es decir, que al importarlo con sus parámetros, reciba un map y se rellene automáticamente una vez importado y pasándole como parámetro el mapa, pero no se como hacerlo.

Tengo el componente Table, que es una función con parámetros, y luego lo exporto, para que al llamar a ese componente como parámetro le paso un mapa y automáticamente se rellenaría

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

const renderTable = (data) => {
    return <>
        <Table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Movil</th>
                    <th>DNI</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{data.nombre}</td>
                        <td>{data.apellido}</td>
                        <td>{data.movil}</td>
                        <td>{data.dni}</td>
                        <td>{data.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </thead>
        </Table>
    </>
}

export default renderTable;
```

Aqui lo importo pero no se como pasarle el mapa como parámetro, para que se rellene solo

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import Table from './Table'


const baseURL = "http://localhost:2000/backend/crud/api/obtenerRolesAdministrador.php";

const Tabla =()=>{
    const [tabla, setTabla]= useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`${baseURL}`)
            .then((response) => {
                setTabla(response.data);
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err.message) });
    }, []);
    console.log(tabla);
    return 
    {tabla.length ? tabla.map({Table}): ""}
}

export default Tabla;
```

Comment: El componente Table que creaste es medianamente dinámico, ya que, aunque estas recibiendo la data por props, estas indicandole que debe tener las propiedades nombre, apellido, email, etc. Si estas completamente seguro que la data que le vas a pasar a la tabla tiene siempre las mismas propiedades, solo deberías hacer algo así `return (<Table data={dataDesdeAPI} />)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
import Table from './Table';

class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table data={this.props.data} columns={this.props.columns} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo así, modifica tu componente para que acepte prop `data`

```
const renderTable = ({ data }) => {
  // El código que renderiza la tabla
}
```

En el componente `Tabla` en vez de llamar a `Table` directamente lo que vas a hacer es pasar el map como prop.

```
{tabla.length ? tabla.map(item => <Table data={item} />) : ""}
```